# How Onstop Method work for this demo?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am making a demo to understand back stack and activity life-cycle.

I made:

- MainActivity
- MainActivityDialog (another activity theme as dialog)
- BActivity

I launched this app and Main Activity is shown. Then press a button to show the dialog, then MainActivityDialog is opened. Then I again press button on MainActivityDialog then BActivity is opened. Finally, I pressed the back button.

```
MainActivity -> MainActivityDialog -> BActivity ---Back--->  MainActivityDialog
```

Here is the log of this app :

[image: Log message of backstack of this app]

My question are:

1. Why MainActivity get stopped after launching BActivity from MainActivityDialog? Then after BActivity lifecycle method is called, why MainActivityDialog get stopped?
2. After pressing back button in BActivity, MainActivity starts first then MainActivityDialog starts and then MainActivityDialog resume?

Answer (score 1):

The order of calls to `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` on multiple activities is indeterminate.

If you have multiple activities in your activity stack that are no longer visible on screen, Android may call `onStop()` on them whenever it wants to and in whatever order it wants to. This is only an indication to the activity that it is no longer visible to the user. You cannot rely on the order of `onStop()` calls to multiple activities.

The same goes for `onDestroy()`. Android may call `onDestroy()` on an activity once that activity has finished. If you have multiple finished activities in your task, Android may call `onDestroy()` on them whenever it wants to and in whatever order it wants to. This is also indeterminate. The call to `onDestroy()` is just to inform the activity that it is no longer active and that it should release any resources it may have.

There is no guarantee that `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` will **ever be called**. The last lifecycle call that is guaranteed is `onPause()`. After that, Android can just kill the process without calling any further lifecycle methods.

In your second question you want to know why, after the user presses the BACK button on `BActivity`, `MainActivity` starts first followed by `MainActivityDialog`. The reason is that `MainActivity` is visible on screen FIRST and then `MainActivityDialog` is visible on screen **on top of** `MainActivity` (because `MainActivityDialog` is Dialog-themed, it doesn't cover the entire screen and you can see parts of `MainActivity` underneath it).

Answer (score 0):

Im not a pro at Android, but since nobody has answered yet, i will try my best. I want to help because i also learn android by doing something like you did (using log cat to see activiti's current state) for the first time.

> Why MainActivity get stopped after launching BActivity from
>   MainActivityDialog?

Every time you start a new activity, the old activity will always be paused/stopped.

> Then after BActivity lifecycle method is called, why
>   MainActivityDialog get stopped?

Because now the current active activity is `BActivity`, in other word : `MainActivityDialog` is not active/visible hence its stopped/paused.

> After pressing back button in BActivity, MainActivity starts first
>   then MainActivityDialog starts and then MainActivityDialog resume?

Yes, because you started `MainActivityDialog` from `MainActivity`, so `MainActivity` will be restarted first.

Please feel free to comment, im also still learning :)

Comment: my question is why mainActivity onstop called first than mainActivityDialog, when we go to BActivity?

Comment: Sorry i dont know about that one. Maybe its how a "dialog" work. I mean, the parent of "dialog" (activity that started it) will be always stopped first.